# insert multiple rows with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting a multiple row data with foreach() loop. But I don't want to insert a particular row if its value is tax or discount. How do I do that.

my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['finalsave']))
{
  foreach ($_POST['descr'] as $key => $descr)
  {
    $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $idate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idate']);
    $desc1 = mysql_real_escape_string($descr);
    $tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$key]);
    $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location'][$key]);
    $war = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['war'][$key]);
    $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty'][$key]);
    $rate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rate'][$key]);
    $finalamt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['finalamt'][$key]);

    $sql2 = ("INSERT INTO `project`.`master_inventory` (`category`, `idate`, `descr`, `name`, `location`,  `war`, `qty`, `rate`, `finalamt`)
      VALUES ('".$dept."','".$idate."','".$desc1."','".$tags."','".$location."','".$war."','".$qty."','".$rate."','".$finalamt."')");
    $sqlins = mysql_query($sql2);
    //echo $sql2;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if its value is tax or discount` - which value?

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have mentioned.  Its `$_POST['descr']` @Pathik Vejani

Comment: then just put if condition before `foreach` loop

Comment: `if($_POST['descr'] != 'tax' || $_POST['descr'] != 'discount')` I tried like this. But it didn't work.

Comment: please post response for `$_POST['descr']`

Comment: I have 3 post values. tax,iPad,iMac I want to insert only imac and iPad but instead it inserts all 3 rows:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135354/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-vino).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will helps you.

```
 foreach ($_POST['descr'] as $key => $descr)
  {
    if(($descr !="tax")||($descr !="discount"))
    {
       //Write your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: tried it but inserts all rows including row with tax:(

Comment: Can you please share you  $_POST['descr'] output or key and value output.

Comment: **taxIBookIpad mini** Purchase entry saved successfully

Answer (score 1):

Put `if` condition in `foreach` loop like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['finalsave']))
{
  foreach ($_POST['descr'] as $key => $descr) {
  // this you have to do
    if(($descr != 'tax') || ($descr != 'discount'))
    {
      $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
      $idate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idate']);
      $desc1 = mysql_real_escape_string($descr);
      $tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$key]);
      $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location'][$key]);
      $war = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['war'][$key]);
      $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty'][$key]);
      $rate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rate'][$key]);
      $finalamt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['finalamt'][$key]);

      $sql2 = ("INSERT INTO `project`.`master_inventory` (`category`, `idate`, `descr`, `name`, `location`,  `war`, `qty`, `rate`, `finalamt`)
        VALUES ('".$dept."','".$idate."','".$desc1."','".$tags."','".$location."','".$war."','".$qty."','".$rate."','".$finalamt."')");
      $sqlins = mysql_query($sql2);
        //echo $sql2;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I have three values like tax, iPad and iMac. It inserts all three rows. where I want only iPad and iMac to be inserted.

Comment: Thanks. Still inserts all rows including tax:(

Comment: @vino print value for `$descr`

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the value is tax or discount before insert query.

As you said,`descr` field in table contains the value `tax` or `discount` which is assigned to variable `$desc1`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['finalsave']))
{
  foreach ($_POST['descr'] as $key => $descr)
  {
    $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $idate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idate']);
    //this variable $desc1 will have the value tax or discount
    $desc1 = mysql_real_escape_string($descr);
    $tags = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'][$key]);
    $location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location'][$key]);
    $war = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['war'][$key]);
    $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty'][$key]);
    $rate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rate'][$key]);
    $finalamt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['finalamt'][$key]);
    //inserts only if $desc1 is not tax or discount
    if(($desc1!="tax")||($desc1!="discount")
    {
    $sql2 = ("INSERT INTO `project`.`master_inventory` (`category`, `idate`, `descr`, `name`, `location`,  `war`, `qty`, `rate`, `finalamt`)
          VALUES ('".$dept."','".$idate."','".$desc1."','".$tags."','".$location."','".$war."','".$qty."','".$rate."','".$finalamt."')");
        $sqlins = mysql_query($sql2);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: No luck:(. Inserts all rows including row with tax.

Comment: @vino  which field in your insert query has the tax or discount value?

Comment: @vido replace `descr` with `desc1` in the `if` condition

Comment: @vino did you check the way i mentioned above?

Comment: Yes I did tried that too @affaz. Again it inserts all rows.

Comment: @vino which field in your table contains the value tax or discount?

Comment: @vino then you should be comparing it with `$desc1` which should be checked just before insert query